# jQuery animate .hide filter results

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-animate

I've never done much jQuery and I'm unsure whether or not this can even be done.  I have the following jQuery which hides and shows divs based on their ID.  Can this show/hide function be animated in any way?  If so, could you please provide an example?

I'll supply the code here and in a fiddle.

jQuery:

```
var $all = $('div', '#divIssueMenu');
var $filter1 = $('div.filter1', '#divIssueMenu');
var $filter2 = $('div.filter2', '#divIssueMenu');
var $filter3 = $('div.filter3', '#divIssueMenu');
var filters = {
all: $all,
filter1: $filter1,
filter2: $filter2,
filter3: $filter3
}
$('#filters a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$all.hide();
filters[id].show();
});
```

HTML:

```
                <div id='filters'>Refine by: <a href='#' id='filter1'>Work</a> | <a href='#' id='filter2'>Personal</a> | <a href='#' id='filter3'>Magento</a> | <a href='http://www.mylessanigar.co.uk/blog/blog.html' id='all'>Reset</a><br> </br>
                </div>
                <div id="divIssueMenu">

                    <div id="rpMenu_divMenu_0" class="filter1"><p class="blogpostinfo">Posted by Myles. 28/10/2013</p>Welcome to my blog<br> </br></div>

                    <div id="rpMenu_divMenu_1" class="filter2"><p class="blogpostinfo">Posted by Myles. 28/10/2013</p>Welcome to my blog<br> </br></div>

                    <div id="rpMenu_divMenu_3" class="filter3"><p class="blogpostinfo">Posted by Myles. 28/10/2013</p>Welcome to my blog<br> </br> </div>

                    <div id="rpMenu_divMenu_3" class="filter3"><p class="blogpostinfo">Posted by Myles. 28/10/2013</p>Welcome to my blog<br> </br> </div>

                    <div id="rpMenu_divMenu_3" class="filter3"><p class="blogpostinfo">Posted by Myles. 28/10/2013</p>Welcome to my blog</div>
```

This can be seen working perfectly here: http://jsfiddle.net/5g3zV/

All I need to do is make it look nicer!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Be7YU/3)</kbd>

```
var $all = $('#divIssueMenu')
$('#filters a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    if (id === 'all') {
        $all.find('div').show();
    } else {
        $all.find('div').hide();
        $all.find('.' + id).show();
    }
});
```

---

[.show(duration)](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete)

[.hide(duration)](http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete)

> duration (default: 400)

---

[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
var $all = $('#divIssueMenu')
$('#filters a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    if (id === 'all') {
        $all.find('div').show();
    } else {
        $all.find('div').hide();
        $all.find('.' + id).stop(true, true).animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 800);
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo with animation**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Be7YU/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an argument (number of milliseconds) to `show()` or `hide()` which will animate the transition.

If you want further control, look into the `animate()` method.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Any suggestions on how to pass an argument here..?

$all.hide();
filters[id].show();